# Qt QML change item of a page dynamically

Tags: qt, qml

I have BasePage.qml like this:

```
Item {
    property alias content: loader.sourceComponent
    signal topBarLeftButtonClicked()

    TopBar {
    ...
    }

    Loader {
        id: loader
    }

    BottomBar {
    ...
    }
}
```

This way I can change dynamically the content of the page, but I must use Component, and I can't read properties of the content in a DerivedPage.
For example:

DerivedPage.qml

```
BasePage {
    onTopBarLeftIconClicked: item.text //error, item is not defined

    content: Component {
        TextField {
            id: item
        }
    }
}
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to replace loader and components:

```
//BasePage.qml
Item {
    default property alias data: item.data
    signal topBarLeftButtonClicked()

    TopBar {
    ...
    }

    Item{
        id: item
    }

    BottomBar {
    ...
    }
}

//DerivedPage.qml
BasePage {
    onTopBarLeftIconClicked: textField.text = "string"

    TextField {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: textField
    }
}
```

This way textField replace item in BasePage.qml

Answer (score 2):

You can define an alias to the `Loader`'s `item` property inside `BasePage`, like that:

```
property alias contentItem: loader.item
```

And refer to it instead of <del>`content`</del> `item` within `DerivedPage`.

---

Putting it all together:

```js
// BasePage.qml
Item {
    property alias content: loader.sourceComponent
    property alias contentItem: loader.item
    signal topBarLeftButtonClicked()
    Loader { id: loader }
}

// DerivedPage.qml
BasePage {
    onTopBarLeftIconClicked: { contentItem.text = "clicked" }
    content: Component { TextField { } }
}
```

Comment: Gives me this error: Invalid property assignment: "contentItem" is a read-only property

Comment: Oh, sorry. I mean use it instead of `item`, not `content`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit, it worked. But if my content is an Item with nested children? How can I access to them?